# How to make ion-input disabled?

Tags: typescript, ionic-framework

How can I disable `ion-input`?

```
<ion-input type="text"></ion-input>
```

I'm new at Ionic Framework, it is rather similar to HTML, but there is no property for attribute to disable it like:

`.prop("disabled", true)`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Ionic 2:

1. Static property:

   ```
    <ion-input disabled="true" type="text"></ion-input>
   ```
2. Dynamically:

   ```
   <ion-input disabled="{{isDisabled}}" type="text"></ion-input>
   ```

   After in the component(.ts file):

   ```
   private isDisabled: boolean=false;
   ```

Comment: Its not working for me, I am using ion-input in from group. Please help

Comment: @Himankshah I think the problem is no the form group. You must have a flag for every form field from your .ts file. If you have a form fields dynamically, so you can set the flag attribute to your model.

Comment: see I am trying like this :       <ion-item class="bgtransparent">
                                             <ion-label floating class="whitecolor">Email</ion-label>
                                           <ion-icon name="md-mail" item-left></ion-icon>
      <ion-input disabled="{{isDisabled}}"
        [class.invalid]="!confirmationForm.controls.email.valid && (confirmationForm.controls.email.dirty)"
        formControlName="email" type="email" class="whitecolor"></ion-input>
    </ion-item>

Answer (score 1):

disabled in small characters, it works on the boolean mechanism. 
bind the object of true and false so you will get the result.

```
<ion-input disabled="{{inputDisabled}}" [(ngModel)]="drill_plus" placeholder="Drill Plus" type="number"></ion-input>
```

your ts
export class

```
inputDisabled: boolean = false;
```

condition

```
this.inputDisabled = true;
```

works for me.
try this, hope you will get the answer.

Answer (score 1):

if you want to disable the input field without any condition you can use **disabled directive** like this:

```
<ion-input type="text" placeholder="Enter Input" disabled></ion-input>
```

if you want to disable the input field on some condition, you can define a variable in your typescript file and assign it to **disabled directive** like this:

**example.ts:** 
private isDisabled: boolean = false;

**example.html**

```
<ion-input type="text" placeholder="Enter Input" [disabled]="isDisabled"></ion-input>
```

so if **isDisabled** variable's value is true,it will be disabled, otherwise it will enable and user can input whatever he/she wants.

Hope it will help some one in future. 
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

`Disabled` will make the text on the input to fade but if you are looking to still display the text like a `readonly` mode, you can try the following code snippet:

```
<ion-input type="email" readonly="{{isDisabled}}" [(ngModel)]="registerEmail" placeholder="abc@example.com"></ion-input>
```

The input will still be active but the user will not be able to edit or change what's on the input.